# Где-то ошибка в запросе (batchInsert)

Tags: yii2

> PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Class
>   'app\commands\Yii' not found'
>
> in
>   /home/c/co75701/yii2/public_html/commands/CountriesController.php:36

**Stack trace:** 
0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()
1 {main}

36 строка - это начало запроса из 3-х строк:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert('countries', ['country'],
    $countries
)->execute();
```

`$countries` - обычный массив стран.

Comment: есть ли у вас в контроллере строка `use app\commands\Yii` ?

Comment: Добавьте `use yii;` или слеш перед обращением `\Yii:$app`. P.S. Обычно IDE(PhpStorm точно) подсказывают об отсутствии декларирования.

Comment: use app\commands\Yii - прописано, а если ставлю слеш перед \Yii:$app, то выходит ошибка: with message 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'

in /home/c/co75701/yii2/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/QueryBuilder.php:214

Comment: Что значит "обычный массив стран"? Что конкретно лежит в `$countries`? Скорее всего проблема в этом массиве

Comment: замените `use app\commands\Yii` на `use \Yii`, если у вас нет конечно такого класса, который тут используется. Если есть то или как вам выше написали, или используйте альянсы в `use`. Ошибка `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` не относится к вопросу, но возможно просто `$countries` пуст, или в другом месте ошибка.